# How to download angular material demo

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I try to copy [this demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menuBar)'s html, css and js to local, the view is messy:

[image]

here is my [full code](https://gist.github.com/roroco/904d37d4df9c868dc5c99c4f1978c480), how to make it like online demo view

Answer (score 0):

I find I miss angular-material.css

- I find the all css and scripts in [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started)
- here is my [full code](https://gist.github.com/roroco/c3e09476e8412befe1fe44ad912c2be4)
- svg-assets-cache.js can be found in [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwi27pbb0ozRAhXBqY8KHbYRA7kQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fangular%2Fmaterial%2Ftree%2Fmaster%2Fdocs%2Fapp&usg=AFQjCNEzKKn31swIDG0Tbu-xJkISNwQy0A&sig2=_-_r-8qhI4ZPr4Ep3sqb4Q)

Answer (score -1):

please open that code in codepen and export this code

for ref go to: https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/features/exporting-pens/

Thanks